# Replaced battery... However

Tags: electrical, battery

We have a 2000 Jeep Grand Cherokee.  Finding out our battery needed to be replaced, we got another one. The car started and ran fine for a few days. The next time I went to start it, it clicked over for a second then went dead. No lights, nothing.

Answer (score 3):

There's 2 possibilities:

- your alternator is dying: get it tested at a parts store
- you have an occasional short somewhere: inspect your battery cables, inspect all your fuses

Answer (score 0):

How was it starting? Did you notice if it was starting to crank slower towards the end? Or was it still cranking strong the day before it went dead? If it was still cranking strong then your alternator is probably good, if it wasn't checking the alternator would be a good idea.

The first thing to do is to see if there was something that drew down the battery "normally" – perhaps the lights were left on, or an inverter was left running. Just because a new battery went dead doesn't mean that there is something wrong.

It may be too late to figure out what happened, so just jump (or charge) the battery and pay attention to how the car starts the next time. If it cranks vigorously that's a good sign. Pay attention for the next couple of days, if it keeps cranking strong and starting reliably then it could be that something was left on and the dead battery is just a coincidence. But if you notice any tendency towards slower cranking when you try to start the car or less reliable starting then it is time to investigate further.

If the problem develops over several days (or trips) then it is likely that the alternator, or some other component in the charging system, is the culprit. If it starts well after a short stop, but seems to have more and more trouble starting the longer the car sits, then there may be a drain on the battery while the car is sitting. Check for lights that are left on, or something plugged into one of the 12 V outlets (the things we used to call cigarette lighters).